# Why can't a reference to a not imported module be made if the same module is imported in error-handling?

Tags: python, recursion, try-except, recursionerror

Given this python script:

```
def s():
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except NameError:
        import time
        s()


for i in range(10):
    s()
    print(i)
```

This gives me a RecursionError, but I don't see why because I would expect it to:

1. Call the `s` function
2. Cause a NameError in the try clause, as time is not yet imported
3. Import time in the except clause
4. Call itself
5. Succeed in the try clause, sleeping for 1 second
6. print `0`
7. Succeed in the try clause all successive times, printing numbers up to 9 with 1 second in between them.

I cannot see why it would call the `s()` function recursively more than 2 times.

For clarification purposes:

1. I only want to import the module if it wasn't already imported.
2. I only want to import the module if the function is called.

Comment: Why not just put `import time` at the beginning of the function? If the module has already been imported it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why do you want to do the `import` in the function? Just put `import time` at top-level before the function.

Comment: @fedsavi You can put `global time` right after `def s():` but that's bad practice. Just import the `time` module normally.

Comment: But what if 1.) I only want to import the module if it wasn't already imported 2.) I only want to import the module if the function is called. How would I make a check for that? @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `import` is inside a function, names it defines are local to that function's scope by default. To make it global, use `global time`.

```
def s():
    global time
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except NameError:
        import time
        s()
```